# Updating column in access DB after getting which DataGridView CheckBoxes are selected in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, checkbox, datagridview

I am just starting in vb.net and I am trying to update a row in access database that is selected by a DataGridView checkbox in VB.net.

Here is a part of the system:

[image: here is a part of the system]

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub editIO_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles editIO.LinkClicked

        If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            myConnection.Close()
        End If
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()


        If editIO.Text = "Enable Time In/Out Edit" Then
            Try
                Dim CheckedRows =
                    (
                        From Rows In AdminTabDisplay.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
                        Where CBool(Rows.Cells("ck").Value) = True
                    ).ToList
                If CheckedRows.Count > 0 Then

                    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
                    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In CheckedRows
                        sb.AppendLine(row.Cells("Last Name").Value.ToString)

                    Next
                    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Roster1] SET [EditTime] = 'e' WHERE [Last Name] = '" & sb.ToString & "'", myConnection)
                    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader




                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
        viewAdmin()
        editIO.Text = "Disable Time In/Out Edit"
    End Sub
```

It can check which checkboxes are selected and can update the whole database when the link is clicked.

But every time I add a "WHERE" clause after db command (Which is "WHERE [Last Name] = '" & sb.ToString & "'"), It doesn't update the selected row.

Also, I would like to use the "Employee ID" column in replacement of the "Last Name" column used in the WHERE clause

If possible, please explain it as simple as can be. I'm still a beginner in VB.net. Thank you very much! Every help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind my post. I solved it with a tiny detail.

I used the "Employee ID" column instead of the "Last Name" column as shown in the code above

It was converted to string (because of the stringBuilder). But I converted it to an Integer with the code:

```
           Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
           For Each row As DataGridViewRow In CheckedRows
                sb.AppendLine(row.Cells("Last Name").Value.ToString) 
           Next    
                Dim st As String = sb.ToString
                Dim value As Integer = CInt(st)
```

and Changed the database command to:

```
                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Roster1] SET [EditTime] = 'e' WHERE [Employee ID] = " & value & "", myConnection)
                Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
```